# How to decode a json with nested dictionaries using Codable protocol

Tags: json, swift, codable

I'm trying to decode the json below using codable protocol :

```
let jsonData = """
{
    "request_state": 200,
    "dynamic_value_1": {
        "temperature": {
            "sol":285.1
        }
      },
    "dynamic_value_2": {
        "temperature": {
            "sol":405.1
        }
    }
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!
```

I created the object with a custom init in order to correctly map the json response. But I don't know how to map the

```
public struct Periods: Codable {
    public var innerDict: [String: InnerValue]

    public struct InnerValue: Codable {
        public let temperature: Temperature
    }

    private struct CustomCodingKeys: CodingKey {
        var stringValue: String
        init?(stringValue: String) {
            self.stringValue = stringValue
        }
        var intValue: Int?
        init?(intValue: Int) {
            return nil
        }
    }

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CustomCodingKeys.self)

        self.innerDict = [String: InnerValue]()
        for key in container.allKeys {
            let value = try container.decode(InnerValue.self, forKey: CustomCodingKeys(stringValue: key.stringValue)!)
            self.innerDict[key.stringValue] = value
        }
    }
}
```

Then when I'm trying to decode with :

```
let model = try JSONDecoder().decode(Periods.self, from: jsonData)
```

I have this error :

```
▿ 0 : CustomCodingKeys(stringValue: "request_state", intValue: nil)
  - stringValue : "request_state"
  - intValue : nil
  - debugDescription : "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found a number instead."
  - underlyingError : nil
```

Any help to create my object might be very useful !

Comment: The error occurs because the code tries to decode `request_state` also as dictionary which doesn't work. The error clearly  states that.

Comment: Yes I saw but how can i set the model to fit with the json.

Comment: @kroko Is there any update on the issue? Does the answer fix your issue? Would you like to mark the answer as accepted for future readers to know about the correctness?

Answer (score 1):

You have to consider the `request_state` case and decode an `Int`

```
public struct Periods: Decodable {
    var requestState = 0
    public var innerDict = [String: InnerValue]()

    public struct InnerValue: Decodable {
        public let temperature: Temperature
    }

    public struct Temperature: Decodable {
        public let sol: Double
    }

    private struct CustomCodingKeys: CodingKey {
        var stringValue: String
        init?(stringValue: String) { self.stringValue = stringValue }
        var intValue: Int?
        init?(intValue: Int) { return nil }
    }

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CustomCodingKeys.self)

        for key in container.allKeys {
            if key.stringValue == "request_state" {
                requestState = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: key)
            } else {
                let value = try container.decode(InnerValue.self, forKey: key)
                innerDict[key.stringValue] = value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Creating the same key again seems redundant. `try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: key)` should be ok.